# unable to display a picture with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to display a picture using xslt and xml. While all other things work and get displayed the the actual picture which path is specified in the photo.xml file inside the tag "picture", is not displayed.

I have a photo.xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pic:photoCatalog xmlns:pic="pictureCatalog">
  <pic:photos>
    <pic:photo>
           <pic:title>Alcazar</pic:title>
           <pic:location>Segovia - Spain</pic:location>
           <pic:picture> pic
           <pic:img src="images/DSC_0183.jpg" orginalwidth="150" />
           </pic:picture>
           <pic:date>Jan 2013</pic:date>
           <pic:camera>Sony</pic:camera>
           <pic:resolution>12px</pic:resolution>
           <pic:format>.jpg</pic:format>
           <pic:description>
            Medieval Castle over the hill overlooking the old city of Segovia.
           </pic:description>
    </pic:photo>
   </pic:photos>

</pic:photoCatalog>
```

Then I have an index.xml file which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="merge.xsl"?>

<pic:catalog xmlns:pic = "pictureCatalog">
    <pic:logo>Logo</pic:logo>
    <Author>User Name</Author>
    <pic:allPhotos>photos</pic:allPhotos>
</pic:catalog>
```

And finally the transformation:

```
 <!-- All the photos-->
   <xsl:template match = "pic:catalog/pic:allPhotos">
     <html>
         <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
         </head>
         <body>

      <!--Loop for the sort-->
    <xsl:for-each select="document(concat(., '.xml'))/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photos">
                <!--point at the fine-->
                <xsl:sort select="pic:photo" />
                 <xsl:value-of select="pic:photo"/><br/>
            </xsl:for-each>

         </body>
   </html>
   </xsl:template>
```

The expected output is a list of pictures with the information from the tags. As I said all works fine but no picture is displayed.

```
<div id="CenterAreaTop">


                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">


           Acqueduct
           Segovia <!--the picture right after this-->
           Jan 2013
           Olympus
           12px
           .jpg

2000 Year old aqueduct built by the romans ca. xxxx during the reign of xxx

.....

 </div>
```

Can anyone help?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected output? Could one issue be because `pic:allPhotos` has the value "photos" while your file is named "photo.xml"?

Comment: true that was not supposed to be, I have fixed it. However, that does not solve the problem. I think there is a problem in the photos path inside the photos.xml. Thnx for  the comment

Comment: Yes, so as I asked: what is the expected output? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: I have edited the question with the expected output. What I am trying to do is displaying the the picture's information, which it is being displayed, and also the picture but the picture is not being displayed. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, how's this:

```
  <xsl:template match = "pic:catalog/pic:allPhotos">
    <html>
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document(concat(., '.xml'))/pic:photoCatalog/pic:photos/pic:photo">
          <xsl:sort select="pic:title" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>          
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pic:photo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    <br />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="pic:img">
    <img src="{@src}" alt="" />
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: hehe.. it is actually great!  The picture is gigantic but it works as intended. thank you much!!!  By the way... is there an easy way to re-size the picture or rather make it smaller ?? thank you again /bluetxxth

Comment: Sure, you can set a width or a height in the second line from the end, like this: `<img src="{@src}" alt="" width="700" />`

Comment: don't use the HTML attributes width or height :
1. it's hardcoded, hence difficult to maintain. Prefer CSS rules ;
2. your image will be resizing client-side and probably get ugly ;
3. the image will be transfer event if it weights 3Mb ! Prefer a server-side resizing and include the resized image.